# Was the Federal Reserve Bailout of $85B to AIG in 2008 'printed money'

Tags: federal-reserve, financial-crises

Was the federal reserve loan of $85 billion to AIG in 2008 done with existing reserves from the Treasury or were new reserves created and exchanged for assets at AIG similar to how the Fed performs monetary policy with government securities?